# How to get past Snowflake SQL UDTF correlated subquery error?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following UDTF defined, where I have confirmed the query works seperate to the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UDF_RETAINED_CUST(period_end date)
    RETURNS TABLE(RETAINED_CUSTOMERS number)
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    AS 
    $$
    SELECT count(DISTINCT po.id_customer)
    FROM STR_PS_ORDERS po
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID_CUSTOMER 
        FROM STR_PS_ORDERS po
        WHERE CURRENT_STATE NOT IN (6, 7, 8)
        AND ORDER_TYPE_ID NOT IN (2, 7)
        AND DATE_ADD >= dateadd(DAY, -181, period_end)
        AND DATE_ADD <= dateadd(DAY, -91, period_end)
    ) prev ON prev.id_customer = po.ID_CUSTOMER 
    WHERE CURRENT_STATE NOT IN (6, 7, 8)
    AND ORDER_TYPE_ID NOT IN (2, 7)
    AND DATE_ADD >= dateadd(DAY, -90, period_end)
    AND DATE_ADD <= period_end
    $$
```

I can also run the function successfully with a single value

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(UDF_RETAINED_CUST(CURRENT_DATE()))
```

The problem is when trying to use this function with a column input from another table.

```
SELECT dd.DATE_SPK, x.retained_customers
FROM DIM_DATE dd 
JOIN TABLE(UDF_RETAINED_CUST(dd.DATE_SPK))) x
```

This prompts the following error:

> SQL Error [2031] [42601]: SQL compilation error:
> Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Comment: try use WITH <common table expressions ...>

Comment: do you mean to use CTE inside the function, or instead of UDFs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with UDFs please have in mind that they are not functions as such. On runtime they are unwrapped and the code is used to substitute in the original query - so to make sure your function is going to work you can test it by simply placing that piece of code into the main query and seeing how that compiles, ie:

```
FROM DIM_DATE dd 
JOIN 
    SELECT count(DISTINCT po.id_customer)
    FROM STR_PS_ORDERS po
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID_CUSTOMER 
        FROM STR_PS_ORDERS po
        WHERE CURRENT_STATE NOT IN (6, 7, 8)
        AND ORDER_TYPE_ID NOT IN (2, 7)
        AND DATE_ADD >= dateadd(DAY, -181, dd.DATE_SPK)
        AND DATE_ADD <= dateadd(DAY, -91, dd.DATE_SPK)
    ) prev ON prev.id_customer = po.ID_CUSTOMER 
    WHERE CURRENT_STATE NOT IN (6, 7, 8)
    AND ORDER_TYPE_ID NOT IN (2, 7)
    AND DATE_ADD >= dateadd(DAY, -90, dd.DATE_SPK)
    AND DATE_ADD <= period_end) x
```

In your case the problem seems to be in the correlated subquery that you have in the function - the use of those in Snowflake is very limited and (among the others) such subquery is only allowed to return a single result regardless of values involved.

To make this work you'd need to rewrite the query getting rid of correlation inside subquery

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you have an example of how to test the code in the main query ? As the function worked for the single value, I would have thought the query is valid. Also the subquery in the function doesn't have any reference to the outer query, so is it still correlated ?

Comment: you're using dd.DATE_SPK there, so it's definitely correlated.

and putting the example in main answer as it's too long for comment